# SwiftUI ScrollView detect direction

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview

I have many rows and columns in one scrollView. I want to scroll to one direction at one time.
That is when swipe vertically then disable horizontally, vice versa.

When I set:

```
ScrollView(.vertical) {}
```

or

```
ScrollView(.horizontal) {}
```

separately, the result is what I need.

So my idea is detecting the gesture direction `scrollVertically`

```
ScrollView( scrollVertically ? . vertical : .horizontal ) {}
```

Then should works. Is it possible in SwiftUI or other solutions? Thanks.

**Test Code**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader(content: { geometry in
            ScrollView([.horizontal]) {
                VStack(spacing: 0, content: {
                    ForEach(0..<30, id: \.self) { value1 in
                        HStack(spacing: 0) {
                            ForEach(0..<30, id: \.self) { value2 in
                                Text("\(value1) - \(value2)").background(Color.red)
                                    .frame(width: 100, height: 40)
                            }
                        }.padding(EdgeInsets())
                    }
                })
            }.background(Color.yellow)
        })

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing axis will recreate ScrollView (with all content) and you get lost state, so this is not the way.

Comment: The following may help you out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59342384/how-to-detect-scroll-direction-programmatically-in-swiftui-scrollview